# Google Apps Email for new Primary Youtube Email

Tags: youtube, google-workspace, google-account

I have a YouTube account that I want to change the primary email for but every time I try to add a alternate address it says it is already associated with another google account.

The email is a google apps user because I want to manage my domains email through gmail.

I have already tried deleting the account and re-creating it to make sure it is not associated with anything.

The only way I can add it is if I delete the google apps account but then I can not verify since I need to access the verification email.

Answer (score 1):

You want to sign into YouTube with the new email, not try to "add" that to your existing account. Your videos and all the things associated with that account will remain with your old email.

Comment: I know you can add alternate emails to accounts and this is what I am trying to do at the very least. It is also on a weird temp sort of email

Comment: @MLM - Those temporary Google Apps emails are not to be used for anything unless your domain name's MX records are not resolving. I'm not really sure what you're asking, it's not presented clearly.

Comment: What I mean to say is that is not a desired email and there is a option to add alternate email addresses to your youtube account. I have an email that I want to use from my domain but I access the email through Gmail with the Apps account. This makes my email somehow connected to a google account so I can not add it as an alternate as it gives me the error. All I need is Gmail for accessing email.

Comment: @MLM - I understand. Your account, with YOUR domain, is actually a Google account. Use that to sign into Youtube. (I would use `someone@ionfish.org` to sign into Youtube since we use Google Apps). Don't try to add that email as an alternate to your current Youtube account. (Or, try what I just mentioned and report the results).

Comment: I can make a whole new youtube account that way but I have  videos already on the account I want to add a email to. So the only way I can use that email is move it back to my server?

Comment: @MLM - Well, you would have to first delete your entire Google Apps account. Then it may not even work still, because Google keeps all of those files and information. So, the only safe way, is to lose all of the videos (they will still be under the current account) but you'd have to start a new account. And by `"Make a whole new Youtube account"` it's really, "I already have a Youtube account with my new email, I just have to sign in"